# How to Upload data to Heroku ? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My Rails app is about an Online Shopping site.
I'm trying Deploy it to Heroku.
I've done push to heroku,and rake db:migrate.

But now in the My web,it doesn't have any Data.

In the localhost:3000,I can show Products,Phones,Users,etc.
But in my web:https://boiling-bayou-5793.herokuapp.com/welcome/home

It doesn't show anything.
So what should I do to upload data from my PC to my web

Comment: You should see your logs to see if it has any info, see more at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data from your local development database is not automatically transferred to the production environment. There is no rake task to do that.

You can use [seed files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) and the `rake db:seed` task to get some initial data in your (production) database.

Answer (score 1):

A more heroku-specific method could be just loading a database dump.
Assuming you're using Postgresql, n your local computer do

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U username -Fc dbname > db.dump
```

upload the file somewhere on the internet (like Amazon S3 so you can get a direct download link) and then on heroku run

```
heroku pgbackups:restore SHARED_DATABASE http://www.example.com/db.dump
```

Remember to remove the db dump right away if it's any kind of sensitive data!